# Doing a qt network request

Tags: c++, qt, networking

Im trying to connect to a website and perform a request with qt, i got this code so far, but it tells me the following mistakes :

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QNetworkRequest>
#include <QNetworkReply>
#include <QUrl>
#include <QUrlQuery>

void sendRequest();

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { 
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    sendRequest();
    return a.exec();
}

void sendRequest() {    
QNetworkAccessManager *manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);   connect(manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),      this, SLOT(replyFinished(QNetworkReply*)));

manager->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl("http://qt-project.org")));
}
```

It says :

> Error 1   error C2355: 'this' : can only be referenced inside non-static
>   member functions or non-static data member
>   initializers  c:\Users\Synturas\documents\visual studio
>   2013\Projects\qt_request\qt_request\main.cpp  19  1   qt_request
>
> Error 2   error C2355: 'this' : can only be referenced inside non-static
>   member functions or non-static data member
>   initializers  c:\Users\Synturas\documents\visual studio
>   2013\Projects\qt_request\qt_request\main.cpp  21  1   qt_request
>
> Error 3   error C3861: 'connect': identifier not
>   found c:\Users\Synturas\documents\visual studio
>   2013\Projects\qt_request\qt_request\main.cpp  20  1   qt_request
>     4   IntelliSense: 'this' may only be used inside a nonstatic member
>   function  c:\Users\Synturas\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\qt_request\qt_request\main.cpp  19  61  qt_request
>
> 5   IntelliSense: identifier "connect" is
>   undefined c:\Users\Synturas\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\qt_request\qt_request\main.cpp  20  2   qt_request
>
> 6   IntelliSense: 'this' may only be used inside a nonstatic member
>   function  c:\Users\Synturas\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\qt_request\qt_request\main.cpp  21  3   qt_request

(Im using VS2013 for this project, if this is relevant)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this example:

Explain:you create new class which will work all job for you, create instance of this class in main.cpp and call method.

*.h

```
#ifndef NET_H
#define NET_H

#include <QObject>

#include <QtCore>
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QNetworkReply>

class Net : public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT
  QNetworkAccessManager *manager;
private slots:
  void replyFinished(QNetworkReply *);//slot, we want catch responce
public:
  void CheckSite(QString url);//our method
};



#endif // NET_H
```

*.cpp

```
#include "net.h"

void Net::replyFinished(QNetworkReply *reply) //this slot called when we have responce
{ 
qDebug() << reply->readAll(); //we read result and print it(also you can save it in some variable and use in code
}

void Net::CheckSite(QString url) 
{
  QUrl qrl(url);//QUrl has network adress
  manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);//create manager
  connect(manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(replyFinished(QNetworkReply*)));//do connection with nededed signal and slot which we alredy wrote
  manager->get(QNetworkRequest(qrl));//send get request
}
```

main

```
#include "net.h"


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    Net handler;//create instance
    handler.CheckSite("http://qt-project.org");//set path and wait for responce

    return a.exec();
}
```

Result: html code of Qt site

Comment: @Synturas we can do it here, result of this messages can be seen in web and every who want learn something new can read it. See my edit please, I added explain and wrote comments for every important line.

Comment: Nice explanation, understood everything ! But why didnt it worked my way ?

Comment: @Synturas The main mistake is in `QNetworkAccessManager(this)`, you try to set parent to QNetworkAccessManager in main cpp, only QObject subclass can be a parent for another class. Second: you try to do connect, but connect is static method of QObject, so it should be at least `QObject::connect`, but your code can't do something, because you didn't provide slot which can catch info and print it(replyFinished slot in my answer do this)